# jQuery - JSON Option Filters

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've created this JSON business directory and a bit of help getting my country dropdown filter to generate dynamically based on the relevant JSON field content. Now I'm trying to duplicate this function for the state and the city fields.

I can get the fields to populate correctly, but they don't function and the matter of empty fields appearing in the list becomes an issue (lots of blanks). I tried a conditional toggle on the option field values for that but it would wouldn't work.

My goal is to have the State and City dropdowns un-selectable until a Country is chosen - then both of the other fields would become available to choose from, and only being populated by fields from items in the selected country. Maybe I'm trying to do too much, but I've been working on this all day and keep having to scrap everything and try again. If anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate your help with this one!

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("#countryFilter, #stateFilter, #cityFilter, #customsFilter, #originalsFilter, #orderFilter").on("change",function(){
            var country = jQuery("#countryFilter").val().toLowerCase();
          var country = jQuery("#stateFilter").val().toLowerCase();
          var country = jQuery("#cityFilter").val().toLowerCase();
            var customs = jQuery("#customsFilter").is(":checked");
            var originals = jQuery("#originalsFilter").is(":checked");
            var order = jQuery("#orderFilter").is(":checked");

            var selector = "";
            if (country != "all") selector += ".filter-country-" + country;
            if (customs) selector += ".filter-customs";
            if (originals) selector += ".filter-originals";
            if (order) selector += ".filter-order";

            if (selector.length == 0)
                selector = ".LD_item_wrap";
            else
                selector = ".LD_item_wrap" + selector;

            jQuery(".LD_item_wrap").hide();
            jQuery(selector).show();
  });

        jQuery.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/it5hh.json", function(data){
            jQuery.each(data, function(i, field) {
                var name = field.NAME;
                var url = field.URL;
                var customs = field.CUSTOMS;
                var ones = field.ONE_OFFS;
                var originals = field.ORIGINAL_MODELS;
                var order = field.ORDER_ONLINE;
                var city = field.CITY;
                var state = field.STATE;
                var country = field.COUNTRY;
                var luthier = field.LUTHIER;
                var email = field.EMAIL;
                var tel = field.TEL;
                var store = field.STORE;
                var info = field.INFO;
                var specialty = field.SPECIALTY;
                var school = field.SCHOOL;
                var classString = "filter-country-" + country.toLowerCase();
                if (customs == "Yes") classString += " filter-customs";
                if (originals == "Yes") classString += " filter-originals";
                if (order == "Yes") classString += " filter-order";
    var uniqueElements = []

    function CheckIfExists(field) {
        var exists = false;
        jQuery.each(uniqueElements, function (i2, field2) {
            if (field2.COUNTRY == field.COUNTRY) {
                exists = true;
                return true;
            };
        });
        return exists;
    }

        jQuery.each(data, function (i, field) {
            if (!CheckIfExists(field)) {
                uniqueElements.push(field)
            }
        });
        jQuery('#countryFilter').empty();
        jQuery('#countryFilter').append(jQuery('<option>', {
                value : 'All',
                text : 'All'
            }))
        jQuery.each(uniqueElements, function (i, item) {
            jQuery('#countryFilter').append(jQuery('<option>', {
                    value : item.COUNTRY,
                    text : item.COUNTRY
                }));
        });
                jQuery("#show-data").append("<div class='LD_item_wrap " + classString + "'>  <div class='LD_1'><h3>" + name + "</h3></div><div class='LD_2'>" + "<a class='LD_lnk' rel='nofollow' href='" + url + "'" + "target='_blank'>" + url + "</a>" + "</div>  <div class='LD_lctn'><div class='LD_7'>" + city + "</div><div class='LD_8'>" + state + "</div><div class='LD_9'>" + country + "</div>  </div><div class='LD_3'>Custom Builds?<span>" + customs + "</span></div><div class='LD_4'>One-Offs?<span>" + ones + "</span></div><div class='LD_5'>Original Models?<span>" + originals + "</span></div><div class='LD_6'>Order Online?<span>" + order + "</span></div>  <div class='LD_cntct_div'>Contact Details</div>  <div class='LD_cnt_cnt'>  <div class='LD_10'><sup>Luthier</sup><span>" + luthier + "</span></div>    <div class='LD_11'><sup>Email</sup><span>" + "<a class='LD_MF' href='mailto:" + email + "' target='_top'>" + email + "</a></span>" + "</div><div class='LD_12'><sup>Tel</sup><span>" + tel + "</span></div> <div class='LD_13'><sup>Shop</sup><span>" + store + "</span></div>  <div class='LD_14'><sup>Info</sup><span>" + info + "</span></div>  <div class='LD_15'><sup>Specialty</sup><span>" + specialty + "</span></div><div class='LD_16'><sup>School/Course</sup><span>" + school + "</span></div></div></div>");
            });
            jQuery('.LD_MF').each(function() {
                var that = jQuery(this);
                that.attr('href', that.attr('href').replace('[x.x]', '.').replace('[x..x]', '@'));
                that.html(that.html().replace('[x.x]', '.').replace('[x..x]', '@'));
            });

            var check = jQuery('.LD_item_wrap div');
            for (var i = 0; i <= check.length; i++) {
                if (jQuery(check[i]).text() == '') {
                    jQuery(check[i]).css('display', 'none');
                }
            }


            var check3 = jQuery('.LD_item_wrap div span');
            var check2 = check3.parent();
            for (var i = 0; i <= check3.length; i++) {
                if (jQuery(check3[i]).text() == '') {
                    jQuery(check2[i]).css('display', 'none');
                }
            }

            var yn = jQuery('.LD_item_wrap div span');
            for (var i = 0; i <= yn.length; i++) {
                if (jQuery(yn[i]).text() == 'Yes') {
                    jQuery(yn[i]).html('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 426.667 426.667" style="enable-background:new 0 0 426.667 426.667;" xml:space="preserve" width="15px" height="15px"><g><g><polygon points="293.333,135.04 190.08,240.213 137.173,187.093 108.8,215.467 192.213,298.667 326.187,168.747   " fill="#91DC5A"/></g></g><g><g><path d="M213.333,0C95.513,0,0,95.513,0,213.333s95.513,213.333,213.333,213.333s213.333-95.513,213.333-213.333    S331.154,0,213.333,0z M213.333,388.053c-96.495,0-174.72-78.225-174.72-174.72s78.225-174.72,174.72-174.72    c96.446,0.117,174.602,78.273,174.72,174.72C388.053,309.829,309.829,388.053,213.333,388.053z" fill="#91DC5A"/></g></g></svg>');
                }
            }

            for (var i = 0; i <= yn.length; i++) {
                if (jQuery(yn[i]).text() == 'No') {
                    jQuery(yn[i]).html('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 426.667 426.667" style="enable-background:new 0 0 426.667 426.667;" xml:space="preserve" width="15px" height="15px"><g><g><polygon points="303.147,153.813 272.853,123.52 213.333,183.253 153.813,123.52 123.52,153.813 183.253,213.333 123.52,272.853     153.813,303.147 213.333,243.413 272.853,303.147 303.147,272.853 243.413,213.333   " fill="#666666"/></g></g><g><g><path d="M213.333,0C95.513,0,0,95.513,0,213.333s95.513,213.333,213.333,213.333s213.333-95.513,213.333-213.333    S331.154,0,213.333,0z M213.333,388.053c-96.495,0-174.72-78.225-174.72-174.72s78.225-174.72,174.72-174.72    c96.446,0.117,174.602,78.273,174.72,174.72C388.053,309.829,309.829,388.053,213.333,388.053z" fill="#666666"/></g></g></svg>');
                }
            }

            jQuery('.LD_14').hide();          
          jQuery('#LD_aSub').click(function(){
            jQuery('#LD_subWrap').fadeIn();
            jQuery('#show-data').hide();
          });
          jQuery('#LD_subExit').click(function(){
            jQuery('#LD_subWrap').fadeOut();
            jQuery('#show-data').show();
          });
        });
    });
```

```css
/*
https://www.electricherald.com/json/luthierDir.json 
https://api.myjson.com/bins/it5hh.json
*/


.td-post-header {
background:url(https://www.electricherald.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/A019-Facebook-Image-1.jpg);
}
.td-post-header:after {
background:rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
@media (max-width: 1018px) {
h1 {color:#000;background:rgba(255,255,255,.5);}
}
@media (min-width: 1019px) {
h1 {color:#000;background:rgba(255,255,255,.8);}
}


@media (max-width: 739px) {
#LD_LD_WrapWrap {height: 714px; padding:10px; margin: 20px 0px; border:1px #ccc solid; border-radius:20px;}
  #LDWrap {font-family:Lato; color:#666; height:550px; width:100%;}
  #LD_subWrap {display:none; width:calc(100% - 20px); position:absolute; z-index:1000; background:#fff; overflow-y:scroll; overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical; height:662px;}
  #LDX {width:100%; padding:0; margin:0; text-align:center;}
  #LDX h2 {color:#cc4c4c; text-transform: uppercase; font-size:20px; text-shadow:2px 2px 1px #ddd; font-family:Lato; line-height:20px; margin-top:12px;} 
#LDMen {padding:0; margin:0; background:#fafafa;}
  #LDMen h4 {color:#000; font-size:14px; text-transform:uppercase; padding:0; margin:0 0 2px 0; border-bottom:1px #666 solid;}
  #LD_filters {text-align:center; padding:0; margin:12px 0 0 0; font-size:14px; line-height:14px;} 
#LD_subPrompt h5 {text-align:center; padding:0; margin:10px 0 0 0;font-size:12px; text-}
  #LD_subPrompt h5:before {content:'*Luthiers & Guitar Makers: ';}

  #LDInf {margin-top:20px;height:auto;}
  #LDINRES {display:block; color:#000; font-size:14px; text-transform:uppercase; padding:0; margin:0 0 2px 0; border-bottom:1px #666 solid;}
 
  .LD_item_wrap {background:#fafafa; margin:10px 0; padding:10px;}
  .LD_1 h3 {color:#cc4c4c; font-size:20px; padding:4px 0; margin:8px 0; border-bottom:1px rgba(0,0,0,.05) dotted;}
  .LD_2 a {text-decoration:none; color:#000; font-weight:bold; margin:0 5px; font-size:11px; line-height:12px;}
  .LD_2 a:hover {text-decoration:none; color:#cc4c4c;}
  .LD_2 a:active {color:#fff;}
  .LD_lctn > * {display:inline-block; margin:4px 5px;color:#000;}
  .LD_7:after, .LD_8:after {content:',';}
  
.LD_lctn, .LD_2, .LD_3, .LD_4, .LD_5, .LD_6 {text-transform:uppercase; font-size:12px; }
.LD_3, .LD_4, .LD_5, .LD_6 {margin:3px 10px; line-height:14px; max-width:280px; border:1px #fafafa solid;}
.LD_3 span, .LD_4 span, .LD_5 span, .LD_6 span {margin-left:20px; float:right;}
  .LD_cntct_div {margin:20px 0 10px 10px; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; border-bottom:1px rgba(0,0,0,.05) dotted;}
  .LD_cnt_cnt > div {padding:0; font-size:14px; color:#000; max-width:350px; border:1px #fafafa solid; height:26px;}
  .LD_cnt_cnt > div sup {float:left;}
  .LD_cnt_cnt > div span {float:right;}
  .LD_11 > span a {color:#000; text-decoration:none;}
  .LD_11 > span a:hover {color:#cc4c4c;}
  .LD_11 > span a:active {color:#fff;}
  #show-data {height:414px; overflow-y:scroll; overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;}
  #LD_scrl {text-align:center; text-transform:uppercase; font-size:12px; color:#cc4c4c; padding:2px 0;}

#LD_subExit {height:25px; width:25px; position:absolute; top:0px; right:12px; box-shadow:1px 1px 1px #ccc; border-radius:20px; opacity:.7; background: url(https://www.electricherald.com/directoryFiles/X.svg);  z-index:9999; background-size:contain;background-position:center; background-repeat:no-repeat;}
#LD_subExit:hover {opacity:1;}
#LD_subExit:active {box-shadow:1px 1px 3px #000 inset;}


.radio:children {display:inline-block;}
#f7, #f8, #f9, #f10, #f11, #f12 {margin:0 6px;}
label.control-label {margin:0 4px;}
#LDLabel1 {font-size:18px; color:#cc4c4c; text-align:center; width:100%;}
p.description {font-size:9px; text-transform:uppercase; margin-top:0px; color:#ccc;}
.color_span {color:#cc4c4c;}
input.form-control1, textarea.txt_area1 {width:400px; margin:2px; height:24px; outline:none; border:1px #666 solid;
-webkit-transition: all .1s ease;
-moz-transition: all .1s ease;
-ms-transition: all .1s ease;
-o-transition: all .1s ease;
transition: all .1s ease;
border-radius:2px; padding-left:4px;}
input.form-control2 {width:300px; margin:2px; height:24px; outline:none; border:1px #666 solid;
-webkit-transition: all .1s ease;
-moz-transition: all .1s ease;
-ms-transition: all .1s ease;
-o-transition: all .1s ease;
transition: all .1s ease;
border-radius:2px; padding-left:4px;}
input.form-control1:focus, input.form-control2:focus, textarea.txt_area1:focus {border:1px #cc4c4c solid;}
.dbl_col {display:inline-block; width:40% !important;}
.dbl_col2nd {margin-left:50px;}
.form-group {text-transform:uppercase;font-size:14px; padding:10px 0;}
.form-group2 {padding:10px 0;}
.DLfrm_titlh5 {margin:10px 0; padding-left:4px; font-size:16px;}
textarea.txt_area1 {height:60px !important; width:80%; resize:none;}


}


@media (min-width: 740px) {
#LD_LD_WrapWrap {height: 550px; margin: 20px 0px;}
  #LDINRES {display:none;}
#LDWrap {border:1px #666 solid; width:735px; height:500px; margin:0; padding:0; border-radius:20px; box-shadow:1px 1px 1px #ccc; font-family:Lato; color:#666; z-index:20; position:absolute; left:calc(50% - (735px / 2));}
#LDX {width:736px; height:50px; text-align:center;}
#LDX h2 {font-size:24px; text-transform:uppercase; padding:0; margin:0; line-height:50px; font-weight:bold; color:#666; text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #ccc;}
#LDX h2 span {color:#cc4c4c;}
#LDMen {width:130px; height:450px; float:left; padding:0px 10px;}
#LDInf {width:585px; height:450px; float:left;}
#LD_scrl {width:100%; text-align:center; line-height:20px;font-size:12px;color:#ccc;}
#LD_filters {font-size:12px;padding:4px;}
#LD_filters select {display:block;padding:0;outline:none;}
  #cityFilter {margin-bottom:-10px;}
#LD_filters span {margin-left:6px;}
  #LD_filters > input {margin:0 4px 0 15px;}
#LD_filters > * {display:inline-block;margin:4px 0; line-height:10px;}

#LDMen h4 {color:#cc4c4c;text-align:center;}
#show-data {height:calc(100% - 48px); overflow-y:scroll; overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical; margin:10px; padding:5px; background:#fafafa;}





.LD_item_wrap a {color:#000;text-decoration:none;}
.LD_item_wrap a:hover {color:#cc4c4c;}
.LD_item_wrap a:active {color:#fff;}
.LD_item_wrap {margin:20px auto; width:calc(100% - 12px); height:auto;border:1px #ccc dotted;padding:5px; background:#fff;}
.LD_item_wrap div {margin:0;padding:0; line-height:20px;}
.LD_item_wrap div span svg {margin-right:10px; float:right;}
.LD_cntct_div {width:100%; border-bottom:1px #ccc dotted;margin:10px 0px 5px 0px !important; color:#ccc; font-size:12px; text-align:center;}
.LD_cnt_cnt {text-align:center;}
.LD_cnt_cnt sup {float:left;font-size:9px;line-height:20px;text-transform:uppercase;}

.LD_1 {text-align:center;}
.LD_1 h3 {font-weight:bold; margin:0; color:#cc4c4c;}
.LD_2 {font-size:12px; text-align:center;}
.LD_lctn {text-align:center; font-size:12px; text-transform:uppercase; margin-bottom:3px !important; font-weight:bold;}
.LD_7 {display:inline-block;}
.LD_7:after {content:'•';padding:0 4px;}
.LD_8 {display:inline-block;}
.LD_8:after {content:'•';padding:0 4px;}
.LD_9 {display:inline-block;}
.LD_3,.LD_4,.LD_5,.LD_6 {text-transform:uppercase; font-size:12px;}
.LD_10 {}
.LD_11 {font-size:12px;}
.LD_12 {}
.LD_13 {}
.LD_14 {}
.LD_15 {}
.LD_16 {}
  
  
  /*Submission*/
#LD_subPrompt {padding-top:90px;}
#LD_subPrompt h5 {text-align:center; font-size:11px; line-height:16px; font-weight:bold; text-transform:uppercase; color:#666;}

#LD_subWrap {height:calc(100% + 2px); width:calc(100% + 2px); background:#fff; z-index:5000; position:absolute; top:-1px; left:-1px; border:1px #666 solid; border-radius:20px; overflow-y:scroll; overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical; display:none;}

#LD_subForm {width:calc(100% - 20px); padding:10px;}

#LD_subExit {height:25px; width:25px; position:absolute; top:10px; right:10px; box-shadow:1px 1px 1px #ccc; border-radius:20px; opacity:.7; background: url(https://www.electricherald.com/directoryFiles/X.svg); background-size:contain;background-position:center; background-repeat:no-repeat;}
#LD_subExit:hover {opacity:1;}
#LD_subExit:active {box-shadow:1px 1px 3px #000 inset;}


.radio:children {display:inline-block;}
#f7, #f8, #f9, #f10, #f11, #f12 {margin:0 6px;}
label.control-label {margin:0 4px;}
#LDLabel1 {font-size:18px; color:#cc4c4c; text-align:center; width:100%;}
p.description {font-size:9px; text-transform:uppercase; margin-top:0px; color:#ccc;}
.color_span {color:#cc4c4c;}
input.form-control1, textarea.txt_area1 {width:400px; margin:2px; height:24px; outline:none; border:1px #666 solid;
-webkit-transition: all .1s ease;
-moz-transition: all .1s ease;
-ms-transition: all .1s ease;
-o-transition: all .1s ease;
transition: all .1s ease;
border-radius:2px; padding-left:4px;}
input.form-control2 {width:300px; margin:2px; height:24px; outline:none; border:1px #666 solid;
-webkit-transition: all .1s ease;
-moz-transition: all .1s ease;
-ms-transition: all .1s ease;
-o-transition: all .1s ease;
transition: all .1s ease;
border-radius:2px; padding-left:4px;}
input.form-control1:focus, input.form-control2:focus, textarea.txt_area1:focus {border:1px #cc4c4c solid;}
.dbl_col {display:inline-block; width:40% !important;}
.dbl_col2nd {margin-left:50px;}
.form-group {text-transform:uppercase;font-size:14px; padding:10px 0;}
.form-group2 {padding:10px 0;}
.DLfrm_titlh5 {margin:10px 0; padding-left:4px; font-size:16px;}
textarea.txt_area1 {height:60px !important; width:80%; resize:none;}
}



#customsFilter, #originalsFilter, #orderFilter {margin-right:5px;}


div.submit_btn1 {width:70px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;}
button.btn-primary {outline:none; height:24px; width:55px; line-height:18px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold; border:1px #666 solid; font-size:11px; border-radius:2px; background:#fafafa; box-shadow:1px 1px 1px #ccc;}
button.btn-primary:hover {color:#cc4c4c; border:1px #cc4c4c solid;}
button.btn-primary:active {box-shadow:1px 1px 1px #666 inset;}
#LD_aSub {text-decoration:none; color:#cc4c4c; cursor:pointer;}
#LD_aSub:hover {color:#000;}
#LD_aSub:active {color:#ccc;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="LD_LD_WrapWrap">
<div id="LDWrap">
<div id="LD_subWrap">
<div id="LD_subExit"></div>
<!-- ---------------------------------- -->
<div id="LD_subForm"><form id="LDsub" action="https://www.electricherald.com/directoryFiles/LDMail.php" autocomplete="on" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="LDsub" novalidate=""><input name="method" type="hidden" value="validateForm" /><input id="serverValidationFields" name="serverValidationFields" type="hidden" value="" /><div class="form-group2" style="margin: none;">
<h4 id="LDLabel1">Directory Submission</h4><div class="radio" style="width: 50%; float: left; display: inline-block;"><input id="fx1" style="float: left; width: 20px; margin-top: 6px;" name="f1" type="radio" value="NEW" /><label style="float: left;" for="fx1">I want to submit a new business.</label></div>
<div class="radio" style="width: 50%; display: inline-block;"><input id="fx2" style="float: left; width: 20px; margin-top: 6px;" name="f1" type="radio" value="EDIT" /><label style="float: left;" for="fx2">I want to edit a current listing.</label></div></div><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label" for="f2">Business Name<span class="color_span"> *</span></label><input id="f2" class="form-control1" name="f2" type="text" value="" placeholder="Feigndor Guitars" data-rule-required="true" /><p class="description">This is your public business/company/brand name, not your personal name.</p></div><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label" for="f3">Web Address</label><input id="f3" class="form-control1" name="f3" type="url" value="" placeholder="http://www.feigndor.com" data-rule-url="true" /></div><div class="form-group required dbl_col"><label class="control-label" for="f4">City<span class="color_span"> *</span></label><input id="f4" class="form-control2" name="f4" type="text" value="" data-rule-required="true" /></div><div class="form-group required dbl_col dbl_col2nd"><label class="control-label" for="f5">State or Province<span class="color_span"> *</span></label><input id="f5" class="form-control2" name="f5" type="text" value="" data-rule-required="true" /></div><div class="form-group required"><label class="control-label" for="f6">Country<span class="color_span"> *</span></label><select id="f6" class="form-control2" name="f6" data-rule-required="true">
<option value="United States">United States</option>
</select></div>
<div class="form-group2">
<h5 class="DLfrm_titlh5">Service Information</h5>
<div class="checkbox"><input id="f7" name="f7" type="checkbox" value="CUSTOMS" /><label for="f7">We build custom guitars.</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><input id="f8" name="f8" type="checkbox" value="ONE_OFFS" /><label for="f8">Our custom designs are not limited (one-off builds).</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><input id="f9" name="f9" type="checkbox" value="ORIGINAL_MODELS" /><label for="f9">We have original instrument models.</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><input id="f10" name="f10" type="checkbox" value="ORDER_ONLINE" /><label for="f10">Customers can order our instruments online (complete transaction + shipping).</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><input id="f11" name="f11" type="checkbox" value="REPAIRS" /><label for="f11">We perform service &amp; repairs.</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><input id="f12" name="f12" type="checkbox" value="SHOP" /><label for="f12">We have a brick and mortar shop.</label></div>
</div>
&nbsp;
<div class="form-group"><label class="control-label" for="f13">Head Luthier's Name</label><input id="f13" class="form-control2" name="f13" type="text" value="" placeholder="Jiminy Cricket" /><p id="f13-help-block" class="description">*Full name please.</p></div><div class="form-group dbl_col"><label class="control-label" for="f14">Phone Number</label><input id="f14" class="form-control2" name="f14" type="tel" value="" placeholder="123-456-7890" /><p id="f14-help-block" class="description">Include country code if you're outside of the USA.</p></div><div class="form-group f15 required dbl_col dbl_col2nd"><label class="control-label" for="f15">Email<span class="color_span"> *</span></label><input id="f15" class="form-control2" name="f15" type="email" value="" data-rule-email="true" data-rule-required="true" /><p id="f15-help-block" class="description">Our site prevents bots from sending you spam.</p></div><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label" for="f16">Do you operate a lutherie school, or offer courses / training?</label>

<textarea id="f16" class="form-control1 txt_area1" name="f16" rows="3"></textarea></div><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label" for="f17">Does your business have a particular focus or specialty?</label><input id="f17" class="form-control1" name="f17" type="text" value="" /><p id="f17-help-block" class="description">Leave this blank if you are a jack of all trades.</p></div><div class="form-group submit submit_btn1" style="position: relative;"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="z-index: 99999;" type="submit">Submit</button></div>
</form></div>
<!-- ----------------------------------------------- -->

</div>
<div id="LDX">
<h2>Custom Guitar Builders Directory</h2>
</div>
<div id="LDMen">
<h4>Filter Results</h4>
<div id="LD_filters">Country:
<select id="countryFilter"></select>
  <select id="stateFilter"></select>
  <select id="cityFilter"></select>
<input id="customsFilter" name="filt_customs" type="checkbox" value="customs" />Custom Builds
<input id="originalsFilter" name="filt_originals" type="checkbox" value="originals" />Original Models
<input id="orderFilter" name="filt_orders" type="checkbox" value="orders" />Online Orders</div>
<!---filters--->
<div id="LD_subPrompt">
<h5>Submit / Edit Your Business Information <span id="LD_aSub">Here</span>.</h5>
</div>
</div>
<div id="LDInf">
<h4 id="LDINRES">RESULTS:</h4>
<div id="show-data"></div>
<div id="LD_scrl">Scroll Down</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think the amount of code may be a bit overwhelming to the one digging in for the first time. You'll probably get more answers if you remove everything that's not part of the issue and reduce the problem to the minimum amount of code. When facing an issue this is also helpful to oneself.

Comment: Yeah you're probably right - I should have addressed this while it was being worked on initially, but I assumed I'd be able to replicate the country list function on my own.

Answer (score 1):

I took some of the HTML code affected by the issue described to start from scratch. I hope it addresses your issue as you expect and you can find it easy to integrate it into your application code.

> My goal is to have the State and City dropdowns un-selectable until a
>   Country is chosen - then both of the other fields would become
>   available to choose from, and only being populated by fields from
>   items in the selected country.

Technically the following code does not make the dropdown unselectable, as it does not disable it. But I don't know if that is a must or simply emptying it does the job for you.

```js
function getByKey(data, key, target) {
  var result = [];
  $(target).append($('<option>',{"id": '', "text": '- select one -'}));
  data.forEach(function(obj, idx, list) {
    if (obj[key] == '') obj[key] = '- empty -';
    if (typeof (result[obj[key]]) == 'undefined') {
      $(target).append($('<option>',{"id": obj[key], "text": obj[key]}));
      result[obj[key]] = [];
    }
    result[obj[key]].push(obj);
  });
  return result;
}

var main = function(jsonURL) {
  jQuery.getJSON(jsonURL, function(data){ 
    
    var States = [];
    var Cities = [];
    var Countries = getByKey(data, 'COUNTRY', '#countryFilter');
    
    $('#countryFilter').on('change', function(e) {
      
      $('#stateFilter').empty();
      $('#cityFilter').empty();
      
      if ($(this).val() == '- select one -') return null;
      
      var country = ($(this).val()=='')?'- empty -':$(this).val();
      States = getByKey(Countries[country], 'STATE', '#stateFilter');
      
    });
    
    $('#stateFilter').on('change', function(e) {
      
      $('#cityFilter').empty();
      
      if ($(this).val() == '- select one -') return null;
      
      var state = ($(this).val()=='')?'- empty -':$(this).val();
      Cities = getByKey(States[state], 'CITY', '#cityFilter');
      
    });
    
  });
}("https://api.myjson.com/bins/it5hh.json");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="LDMen">
  <h4>Filter Results</h4>
  <div id="LD_filters">Country:
    <select id="countryFilter"></select>
    <select id="stateFilter"></select>
    <select id="cityFilter"></select>
    <input id="customsFilter" name="filt_customs" type="checkbox" value="customs" />Custom Builds
    <input id="originalsFilter" name="filt_originals" type="checkbox" value="originals" />Original Models
    <input id="orderFilter" name="filt_orders" type="checkbox" value="orders" />Online Orders
  </div>
  <!---filters--->
  <div id="LD_subPrompt">
    <h5>Submit / Edit Your Business Information <span id="LD_aSub">Here</span>.</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for addressing the hierarchy issue! I've been trying to put your features into the complete code for about three hours now with confusing results. I'm having a hard time removing the references to the country field in the original code and working in the new code - it seems that a good portion of stuff in the overall code is necessary to actually bring the data into the window. Your code gets me some dropdowns but no data filtering occurs after the country level :'(